# Scala concatenate for loop results

Tags: scala, for-loop, concatenation, yield

I'm trying to concatenate 3 sequences as results of individual for loops with yield. I can't get it to work without temporary variables. Does anybody know a better option? The notWorking version gives me a compiler error at the fourth line of the method "illegal start of a simple expression" just after the first ++.

```
def working() : Seq[Seq[Elem]] = {
    val result = for(index <- 0 until COMPLETE_INPUT_CHANNELS) yield {
        getModesOfCompleteInputChannel(index)
    }
    val result2 = for(index <- 0 until INCOMPLETE_INPUT_CHANNELS) yield {
        getModesOfIncompleteInputChannel(index)
    }
    val result3 = for(index <- 0 until OUTPUT_CHANNELS) yield {
        getModesOfOutputChannel(index)
    }
    return result ++ result2 ++ result3
}

def notWorking() : Seq[Seq[Elem]] = {
    for(index <- 0 until COMPLETE_INPUT_CHANNELS) yield {
        getModesOfCompleteInputChannel(index)
    } ++ for(index <- 0 until INCOMPLETE_INPUT_CHANNELS) yield {
        getModesOfIncompleteInputChannel(index)
    } ++ for(index <- 0 until OUTPUT_CHANNELS) yield {
        getModesOfOutputChannel(index)
    }
```

Comment: It is totally fine to store the results in variables here. The second approach would work if you put the for-comprehensions in parens, but it reduces readability.

Comment: Named things benefit readability - I'm not sure why you'd want to get rid of the vals.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this solution ?

```
val tasks = Seq(
    (COMPLETE_INPUT_CHANNELS, getModesOfOutputChannel),
    (INCOMPLETE_INPUT_CHANNELS, getModesOfIncompleteInputChannel),
    (OUTPUT_CHANNELS, getModesOfOutputChannel))

tasks flatMap {
    case (limit, processing) => 0 until limit map processing
}
```

Comment: Maybe a bit too clever than reasonable. It's harder to be  understand by beginners, which is probably the requester case.

Answer (score 6):

Why not this?

```
(0 until COMPLETE_INPUT_CHANNELS).map(getModesOfCompleteInputChannel) ++
(0 until COMPLETE_INPUT_CHANNELS).map(getModesOfIncompleteInputChannel) ++
(0 until OUTPUT_CHANNELS).map(getModesOfOutputChannel)
```

Though I do like M.A.D's solution. Very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, `++` here is treated as a part of the `yield` expression. To make it work, just wrap your `for` comprehensions in parentheses.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to wrap it in parentheses? I haven't found a way that hasn't any compiler error.

Comment: `(for{...} yield {...}) ++ (for{...} yield{...}) ++ ...`